# global asax error

Tags: asp.net

I've suddenly got this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyApp.Global'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MyApp.Global" Language="C#" %>

Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

I have not done anything to Global.asax. I tried to change the namespace from MyFramework to MyApp but It didn't work either so I put it back like it is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace MyFramework
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup

        }

        void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //  Code that runs on application shutdown

        }

        void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

        }

        void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when a new session is started

        }

        void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when a session ends. 
            // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
            // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
            // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `Inherits` attribute and the current code-behind namespace match, if not are you sure it's compiling appropriately?  It it can't find the type in the DLL this will happen, e.g. code file not included in project, etc.

Comment: Thanks I have found the reason finally see below.

Answer (score 1):

I have found why: I have renamed my main Namespace, I thought VS would take care of it.